# DataMash removes a column

Tags: bash

I need to output three columns (word, year, frequency) that describe the word with the highest frequency per year since 1900. I got the year and frequency but lost the word column. Any ideas on how to get it back?

Current Code:

```
zcat ***path to data file*** | awk '$2>=1900' | sort -k 2,2n -k1,1 | datamash -g2 max 3
```

Structure of Data:

```
word TAB year TAB frequency TAB volume_count NEWLINE
```

Desired Output:

```
seen_VERB   1925    321826 
seen_VERB   1932    273366
seen_VERB   1945    220152
seen_VERB   1964    675214
```

Current Ouput:

```
 1925    321826 
 1932    273366
 1945    220152
 1964    675214
```

Comment: `       -f, --full
              print entire input line before op results (default: print only the grouped keys)
`

Answer (score 0):

awk alone can do the filtering (`$2>1900`) but also the job of `datamash`:

```
zcat file |
  awk '$2>1900 && $3>f[$2] {w[$2]=$1; f[$2]=$3}
       END                 {for(y in w) print w[y], y, f[y]}' |
  sort -k2n
```